# How to fetch HTML in Java

Tags: java, html, screen-scraping

Without the use of any external library, what is the simplest way to fetch a website's HTML content into a String?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I'm currently using this:

```
String content = null;
URLConnection connection = null;
try {
  connection =  new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection();
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
  scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
  content = scanner.next();
  scanner.close();
}catch ( Exception ex ) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(content);
```

But not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: Why "\\Z"? Isn't it an EOF on Windows only? I am just guessing here.

Comment: Why do you use "\\Z"? What does it do? I tried without it, it didn't work.

Comment: @MaxHusiv I think it's because if you don't specify a delimiter, scanner.next() will just go through the whole HTML character by character, but if you use a delimiter which won't be found in the HTML, scanner.next() returns the whole thing.

Comment: What import statements do you need for that to work?

Answer (score 23):

This has worked well for me:

```
URL url = new URL(theURL);
InputStream is = url.openStream();
int ptr = 0;
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while ((ptr = is.read()) != -1) {
    buffer.append((char)ptr);
}
```

Not sure at to whether the other solution(s) provided are any more efficient or not.

Comment: Don't you need to include the following?
import java.io.*
import java.net.*

Comment: Sure, but they're core java so very simple. As for the actual code, the import statements are omitted for clarity.

Comment: after `while`, you should display the buffer's content too! or write a method where you read it!

Comment: be sure to `close` the inputstream

Comment: why have you named the variable `ptr`?

Answer (score 2):

I just left [this post in your other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415/quick-way-to-find-a-value-in-html-java), though what you have above might work as well.  I don't think either would be any easier than the other.  The Apache packages can be accessed by just using `import org.apache.commons.HttpClient` at the top of your code.

Edit: Forgot the link ;)

Comment: Apparently you also have to install the JAR file :)

Answer (score 2):

Whilst not vanilla-Java, I'll offer up a simpler solution. Use Groovy ;-)

```
String siteContent = new URL("http://www.google.com").text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
        URL u = new URL("https"+':'+'/'+'/'+"www.Samsung.com"+'/'+"in"+'/');
        URLConnection urlconnect = u.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = urlconnect.getInputStream();
        int i;
        while ((i = stream.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)i);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

Its not library but a tool named curl generally installed in most of the servers or you can easily install in ubuntu by

```
sudo apt install curl
```

Then fetch any html page and store it to your local file like an example

```
curl https://www.facebook.com/ > fb.html
```

You will get the home page html.You can run it in your browser as well.

Comment: *Squints eyes to show shock*. This is a Java Question.