# Bridge between PHP site and Java applet

Tags: java, php, applet

I want to know if it's possible to have an applet communicate with a PHP site and retrieve some information. If so, what approaches can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the PHP page in JAVA Applet, and use JSON/XML format to send data from PHP to Java applet.
JSON or XML would make it easier for you to handle the data.

Answer (score 1):

Your applet could do some URLConnections or HTTPConnections and get the raw text returned by the PHP url.

String myUrl = "http://mysite.com/service.php?param1=yay";

Then use the example [How do you Programmatically Download a Webpage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java) to get the text.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are going to use the HTTP for sending and receiving data, then you can't make it pretty sure, because user has always access to it.