# JSP page to static HTML using Java code

Tags: java, jsp

How do I save a dynamic JSP page to a static HTML page using Java code?

I want to save JSP output to an HTML page and save it on the local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **How do I save a dynamic JSP page to a static HTML page using Java code?**

Once the client receives the JSP page the server has already performed all the "dynamic stuff". So, just download the web page into for instance a `String` using, say, the `URL` class, and write this `String` out to a file. (You won't get the dynamic parts anyway.)

Related question (possibly even duplicates):

- [How do you Programmatically Download a Webpage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java)
- [How do I save a String to a text file using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/i-need-to-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

Write a Java client application that does something like this...

```
URL yahoo = new URL(THE URL OF YOUR JSP PAGE);
URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

String inputLine;
String html;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
   html += inputLine + "\n";
in.close();

// DO SOMETHING WITH THE HTML STRING
```