# how can I download a file using Java?

Tags: java, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you Programmatically Download a Webpage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java)

How to download a file using java. So for example, I want to construct a program which will take some input e.g the website download. and then download the file. Please note that I am not looking for the code or anything. I just want to be pointed in the correct direction and that's it.

Comment: how is this a duplicate, can you not read? I want to download a file not a webpage.... read the question then comment if it is a duplicate or not.

Comment: I can read.  Downloading a file and a webpage over the internet is the exact same process.  Technically speaking, a webpage is a file.

Comment: @jjnguy i want to download a file e.g .pdf .xls etc when i was writing that i was not using techincally terms but terms where your not supposed to technical.

Comment: your accepted answer is using the same process as the question I linked to.  You can download pdfs and excel files over http just the same as you would download html files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to download a file from a URL, have a look at java.net.URLConnection.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this Stack Overflow question:

> [How do you Programmatically Download a Webpage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

By using [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (better than java.net.URLConnection IMHO)

Comment: That link points to a really old version of Java.

Comment: sorry - google's fault. Fixed. Thanks !!!

Comment: Should be this.. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: thanks.  Yes Google still returns at lot of 1.4 results because so many other pages still reference them.

Answer (score 2):

[`URLConnection.getInputStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream%28%29) is what you're looking for. Moving the actual bytes is a bit tedious and error-prone, so if you just want to get it done, using an existing, tested implementation like [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from Apache commons IO would be the best idea.