# How to use java to fill in a web page and pull back the results?

Tags: java, php, post

Hey I am relatively new to java, and I am trying to make an application that does the following:

1. Sends a request to a live website
2. Retrieves the data of that page

For example, assume the following site displays game results, where 'game=500' shows the results for game number 324 of 500 different games. `http://www.some-site.com/results.php?game=324`

I would like to use a Java program to automatically cycle through the game=1 to game=500, posting to the website and retrieving the results of the page.

What is the best way to do this? Can anyone give me a simple example? If I knew the correct java 'key words', I would google for some tutorials on this concept.

Note: the target-page in question is php

Comment: You can write a `curl` one-liner to do that. That is if it fits your requirements and constraints.

Answer (score 3):

```
URL url;
InputStream is = null;
DataInputStream dis;
String line;
for(int i=1;i<=500;i++){
try {
    url = new URL("http://www.some-site.com/results.php?game="+i);
    is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
    dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

    while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null) {
        //do sth with the datea
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
     mue.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
     ioe.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // nothing to see here
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: this works, how ever the site i am trying to get data from is:
http://www.playkeno.com.au/game_results.php

if you visit the page, you have to click "i am 18" in order to enter, since it is lottery related. I have to some-how send the 'i am 18' command to the page :( i'm not too sure how to?

Comment: i used firebug in firefox to check what is being sent. it looks like i need to hit the site:
"http://www.playkeno.com.au/index.php?confirmed=nsw&button=I+am+18%2B"

Answer (score 0):

Do something like the answer in this [other stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java)

and then you want to use a for loop for loop through pages 1 through 500.

Answer (score 0):

Apache has some really good Java libraries for accessing HTTP. [See this](http://hc.apache.org/) for more details.