# Trying to get the source of THIS specific page in Java

Tags: java

I can use this code to get the source of any website I want, except this specific website: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1868015-are-these-some-good-specs-for-a-server/

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException{
        String sURL = "http://minecraftforum.net/topic/2237209-free-kit-god%E2%97%84netrocraft%E2%96%BA-factions-247-auctions-lotto/page__st__320";
        System.out.println(sURL);
        URL url = new URL(sURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //set http request headers
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("Host", "www.cumhuriyet.com.tr");
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36");
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        //httpCon.addRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=EC0F373FCC023CD3B8B9C1E2E2F7606C; lang=tr; __utma=169322547.1217782332.1386173665.1386173665.1386173665.1; __utmb=169322547.1.10.1386173665; __utmc=169322547; __utmz=169322547.1386173665.1.1.utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/questions/8616781/how-to-get-a-web-pages-source-code-from-java; __gads=ID=3ab4e50d8713e391:T=1386173664:S=ALNI_Mb8N_wW0xS_wRa68vhR0gTRl8MwFA; scrElm=body");
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        httpCon.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpCon.setUseCaches(true);

        httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new `InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));`
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            a.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

        System.out.println(a.toString());

        httpCon.disconnect();

    }
```

}

Comment: So does it return an exception or no source? Or rather is it that the source for that page is very brief?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got this code from another question? [How to get a web page's source code from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616781/how-to-get-a-web-pages-source-code-from-java)

However your problem is most likely:
`httpCon.addRequestProperty("Host", "www.cumhuriyet.com.tr");`

You need to change the host url to: 
`httpCon.addRequestProperty("Host", "www.minecraftforum.net");`

Accept this answer to close the question, if it worked. Thanks.