# Write a program to save web-page to a computer

Tags: java, save, local-storage, html

I want to write a program to save web site when we enter web site link. What is the easiest programming language to do that. I want to save entire web site to my computer. I know there is way to write a program to save web page. But my requirement is to save entire web site. How can i do it. I just need some tips. Then i can do some research and find out a solution. Please help me to get start with my work. Thanx.

Comment: We you don't want to use a download manager

Comment: When you say you want to save a website ? Is this any website ? or is this a site you have access to ? , Keep in mind if you say any site you will only be grabbing the HTML content rendered. Any inputs and buttons and other event triggers will not work and if the do they will then "redirect" you to the original site. This is very straight forward for static html sites. Java will easily accomplish what you want.

Comment: Ya.. exactly. I agree with you. But i try to make this happen. Thank for your tips. I will remember things you said when developing. Thank you again for your consideration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are trying to create is actually a download manager. It is easier to create a simple download manager in java but quite tedious to create a full fledged one.

The idea behind it is simple. Say you have a webpage with url www.example.com/index.html. to download just index.html is easy. But to download all pages of a domain or website. You have to download index.html. Then parse index.html for links that are inside domain (ie within www.example.com).You need to download all the links, and then go through all pages downloaded from links and find more links. This goes on till you have parsed all links once. So essentially you would need to read a webpage,grab links and then download those links.You need to search info on web crawler,web page parsing etc.

If you are just trying to download a website please try softwares like flashget,internet download manager etc. There are some opensource once so you could get source as well.

Please go through the links below for more info

http://www.9code.in/java-download-manager-with-full-source-code/

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076095/core-java/download-a-website-for-offline-browsing.html

http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-using-java/

[How to get a web page's source code from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616781/how-to-get-a-web-pages-source-code-from-java)

Comment: This is really helpful. I get really good idea. That what i needed. Your resources are really helpful. Thank you for the support and the time.

Comment: @CharithLakshanWickramasinghe if you found my answer satisfactory please accept it as answer by clicking on big tick mark left side of answer.else if you found it helpfull upvote the answer..that is the stackoverflow way