# How to get web page source from a cookie drived web site using Java

Tags: java, cookies, web

It is easy to get web page source if it has a regular url with it.

Here is an answer for it:
[How to get a web page's source code from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616781/how-to-get-a-web-pages-source-code-from-java)

But some websites, like Sobeys. they are asking you to input your location first then you can get different flyers with different locations. It seems like it is setting up cookies for your preference and then you can get same content of flyers until you close your browser.

My question is, for this kind of webpage, how can I get the web page source of specific flyers (for exmple I want to get the flayers from Sobeys at Danforth Toronto) using Java? I can't use  https://www.sobeys.com/en/flyer  as it appears to be the same all the time. But  how do I get the specific web page source for my flyers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using java to visit https://www.sobeys.com/en/stores/sobeys-danforth/preferred as it sets the cookie you want, otherwise it returns this cookie

```
_carrot-core_session=bCt5WnJadHluUWdlbEVPYkVmb3JQbDc1a2dLWHFYUWw5NlVFVUtUblpRRHJLUEEyZ1MzamN2UjVIWGlSZzBEZDlDUTRxM2JkaEpZeUdNVHh2NUFvVjVxQWM4L015Zm1kaG5wVU5nUytocGRhdzhFMGZvc0pFM090ek41OTVVTy96d2ovTmNBOEdqUDk2dmllUjZoR1BDMEF3S2VCR21SM2thMmlidW01UmIyWmNaRm5sbEZkMjNhRElmakpLd3NvUGxPUTcvdDdlZTZ2UGFWN3BucXZUNkxwWW5ENjZ1TEc1WFpmTlBIT2JsODBkNlI4VHV0S3BuZy81b1JRdytoOS0tdGFpWUIydDNRb1BCeWJPN2psbGxkQT09--b4e4aab475a9d016944bcf0e1207c561e7568b78; domain=.sobeys.com; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Try looking here:
[How to set Cookies at Http Get method using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249137/how-to-set-cookies-at-http-get-method-using-java)

Sorry I can't Help any more.