# java URL file download

Tags: java, url

I am trying to create a java console app which will download a file from a URL.  The file is created at Runtime and I don't know the file name.  When I copy and paste the URL in the browser the save file pop up comes up to save the file.  Now I want to create Java code which logs on to the server (validates user I have that done) go to that URL and download the file.

Comment: Sorry My question is how to implement this.  I wrote code like below and when I run it it returns the HTML code instead of the actual .xlsx file.  I need to change the code so that when the URL is accessed by my app.  The report will be generated and returned at which point I will save the file to the local machine

Comment: As one might expect, there have been **many** questions about how to programmatically download files from a server in Java, such as [How do you Programmatically Download a Webpage in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java).  Voting to close this as a duplicate (please feel free to suggest a more canonical duplicate if you know of one).

Comment: Andrzej that is what I am getting now.  What I want is the file that is created when the URL is accessed

Answer (score 1):

Sergii's answer is a good start; however, if the website you want to use requires more that a simple download, consider using [Apache's HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/features.html).

It supports cookies, authentication, URIs as well as URLs, and file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Simple exapmple from docs, just to put your url insted of http://www.oracle.com/, and change `System.out.println(inputLine);` to write file on disk.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sergii but this will only return the HTML code at that page.

Comment: @Saned - This code will request a *resource* from the server, and will then download the stream of bytes that the server sends in response.  So if the URL is for an HTML page you'll get HTML; if the URL points at a Zip file you'll get the bytes of that Zip file.  I'm not sure what else you could want?

Comment: I have made some update the URL points to a form.  I changed the code to post to that form.  Once the post is completed a file should be generated.  I want to download that file.

Comment: I've written put YOUR url, it means that you should handle moment of generation file, and put url DYNAMICALLY after file will be generated!