# Android download string from webpage

Tags: java, android

I am making an app that will download a string from a website and display it.
I tried many examples online and I've literally been searching for days for this, but I can't find a single solution.

From what I have read, I know I have to get the content of the url from another thread, but no tutorial showed me how to do this.

I have a textview on the layout and that will be where the html content will have to show up.

Can anybody show me an example of how this is done?

Comment: Follow this link please : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview

Comment: I do not want to have any WebView in my app, so this is not the solution

Comment: Sorry I misunderstand your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590899/downloading-a-website-to-a-string includes the case of reading text from a remote site. Displaying a string can then be done using standard android UI elements.

Comment: Sorry, but I've already seen that site about 13 times.
This example does not work in android 4.0, as this requires it to be executed from another thread. As I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... requestUrl) 
    {
        String result = null;

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(requestUrl[0]);

        try
        {
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            result = httpClient.execute(request, responseHandler);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("requestStringFromWebServer", "Whoops!", e);
        }

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        if (result != null)
        {
            // Handle the result from your request here...
        }
    }
}
```

And kick it off with

```
String myUrlStr; // Initialize this to your url
new MyAsyncTask().execute(myUrlStr);
```

Comment: This code does not work in android 4, as we have to do it with an asynctask.

Comment: It works fine in Android 4.  It's easy enough to call this method from the doInBackground of an AsyncTask and deliver the result as a String to be consumed by onPostExecute.

Comment: Mind giving me a full example of this? I've been searching for that for days