# core java program to make http request

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send HTTP request in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)

I have a basic query that I want to write a core Java program that will make a http request.

Let say it will hit and open any website, so how can I write this core java program that will hit the and open any website. I am fully aware that this thing can be achieved with servlets and other advanced framework, also but I want to do it with core Java program.

Please advise how this thing can be achieved in Java?

Comment: [java.net](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/net/package-summary.html) has the classes you need.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java

Comment: I'd recommend [this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Frcp_browser.htm) example

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/).  If you just want to do it with the technology that comes within the JDK, you should look at [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).