# How to search and copy specific string within html linked webpages

Tags: java, php, python, html, perl

Let me describe the problem directly. If you go to the following link, you will see a list of html links which contains stories written by Aesop. Each of the stories contains a moral statement. I need to copy and store only the strings that contains " Moral of Aesops Fable:" I need to get the results as a sequence separated by space or new line.

http://www.taleswithmorals.com/

How can I do it? What platform is easier to use in this case? Can you guide me through please?

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar to this using python and mechanize (a web bot).

You could also just use urllib and parse the response since you know the exact string you are looking for.

I think Python is great for this.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Java has fairly advanced native string handling. If I were trying to do this in java, what I would do is the indexOf(String) method, which returns the first index of a specific substring within that string. Using that, you can look for the html href tags that denote a link (look at the page's HTML source). If you're not sure how to find the HTML file itself, here's [How do you Programmatically Download a Webpage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java) a pretty good explanation of how to pull HTML files using java.
You can then go through the source of each individual page and find the "Moral of Aesop's Fable:" substring, and then save the string immediately following it using Java's PrintWriter, which can write a string to a file: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

Hope this helps!