# How can I make my java program retrieve data sets online?

Tags: java

Currently I am working on a program that will assist me for making decisions when trying to bet on sports. My goal is for the program is that each day I would like to retrieve things like weather, past games, player/team stats etc. then aggregate it all so that I can see which teams make the most sense to bet on.

I'm not exactly sure if it's even possible to do on IntelliJ, the text editor I'm using, because I do not think its connected to the internet on its own. I think one approach would be to use a separate program (not IntelliJ) to automatically go to each website and copy the appropriate information into an excel document; then I could copy the file into my project each day before I run it. Something like that is what I have in mind, but I would appreciate some help if anyone knows which strategy I could use to move past this obstacle.

I've recently learned how to and created a GUI to navigate my program a little easier than through the console; therefore, my work ethic is not an barrier in this instance. I've taken one programming class in college and would consider myself an apprentice (one step above a novice).

Comment: Intellij is just an IDE, a superpowerfull notepad, 'it' is not connected to the internet, but you laptop is, IntelliJ just run your code, using your computer, so you can fetch the a website, you can take a look for ex at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java or other by lookging for 'Java fetch a website"

Comment: You might also want to check out Selenium

Comment: Saying that you have doubts if intellij can be used to write the software you have in mind is like saying you have doubts if the pen you have can write the book you have in mind. IntelliJ or a pen is just a tool for you to write something, that's not where the limits come from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsoup for scraping data from a website, Then you can use Apache POI to add it to an excel file.

Heres the website https://jsoup.org/

Heres a good tutorial about apache POI https://www.baeldung.com/java-microsoft-excel