# Get html file Java

Tags: java

#### Duplicate:

> [How do you Programmatically Download a Webpage in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java)
>
> [How to fetch html in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462/how-to-fetch-html-in-java)

I'm developping an application that consists on: the user inputs an URL of some website, and then the application have to analyze that URL.

How can I have access to the HTML file, using Java? Does I need to use HttpRequest?
How does that works?

Thks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

URLConnection is fine for simple cases. When there are things like redirections involved, you are better off using Apache's [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)

Answer (score 4):

You could just use a URLConnection. See this [Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) from Sun

Answer (score 1):

This code downloads data from a URL, treating it as binary content:

```
public class Download {

  private static void download(URL input, File output)
      throws IOException {
    InputStream in = input.openStream();
    try {
      OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(output);
      try {
        copy(in, out);
      } finally {
        out.close();
      }
    } finally {
      in.close();
    }
  }

  private static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
      throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (true) {
      int readCount = in.read(buffer);
      if (readCount == -1) {
        break;
      }
      out.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");
      File file = new File("data");
      download(url, file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

The downside of this approach is that it ignores any meta-data, like the [Content-Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME), which you would get from using [HttpURLConnection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (or a more sophisticated API, like the Apache one).

In order to parse the HTML data, you'll either need a specialized HTML parser that can handle poorly formed markup or [tidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) it first before parsing using a XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.net.URL and then open an input stream to read the HTML from the server. See the example [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/ReadFromURL.html).

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough I wrote utility method that does just that the other week

```
/**
 * Retrieves the file specified by <code>fileUrl</code> and writes it to 
 * <code>out</code>.
 * <p>
 * Does not close <code>out</code>, but does flush.
 * @param fileUrl The URL of the file.
 * @param out An output stream to capture the contents of the file
 * @param batchWriteSize The number of bytes to write to <code>out</code>
 *                       at once (larger files than this will be written
 *                       in several batches)
 * @throws IOException If call to web server fails
 * @throws FileNotFoundException If the call to the web server does not
 *                               return status code 200. 
 */
public static void getFileStream(String fileURL, OutputStream out, int batchWriteSize)
                            throws IOException{
    GetMethod get = new GetMethod(fileURL);
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpClientParams params = client.getParams();
    params.setSoTimeout(2000);
    client.setParams(params);
    try {
        client.executeMethod(get);
    } catch(ConnectException e){
        // Add some context to the exception and rethrow
        throw new IOException("ConnectionException trying to GET " + 
                fileURL,e);
    }

    if(get.getStatusCode()!=200){
        throw new FileNotFoundException(
                "Server returned " + get.getStatusCode());
    }

    // Get the input stream
    BufferedInputStream bis = 
        new BufferedInputStream(get.getResponseBodyAsStream());

    // Read the file and stream it out
    byte[] b = new byte[batchWriteSize];
    int bytesRead = bis.read(b,0,batchWriteSize);
    long bytesTotal = 0;
    while(bytesRead!=-1) {
        bytesTotal += bytesRead;
        out.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
        bytesRead = bis.read(b,0,batchWriteSize);;
    } 
    bis.close(); // Release the input stream.
    out.flush();        
}
```

Uses Apache Commons library i.e.

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams;
```