# get all data between <div align="center"></div> with java

Tags: java, html, selenium, webdriver

I havn't got any experience with java at all so im a bit lost. With selenium i've downloaded the html of a page and it is stored in a string. Now i'd like to grab all the data between  and put this in array. so in jquery style i'd say it would be something this:

```
$('div[align="center"]').each(function(){
 array[] = $(this).text();
});
```

The difference is now i have to get it out of a string and do it in java. since i havn't got experience with java im looking for the easiest method.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use regex to look for <div align='center'> and then call Zalgo :P

Comment: More seriously, can't selenium return the html to you in a more structured way? Like a dom tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the whole HTML by Selenium (there are lighter tools for that, see [Get html file Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704821/get-html-file-java)), you can pick the right element with Selenium.

If you're using Selenium RC:

```
// assuming 'selenium' is a healthy Selenium instance
String divText = selenium.getText("css=div[align='center']");
```

or if you're using Selenium 2 (WebDriver):

```
// assuming 'driver' is a healthy WebDriver instance
String divText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[align='center']")).getText();
```

If there are actually more `<div align="center">` elements, you can get them all:

```
List<WebElement> divList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[align='center']"));
// and use every single one
for (WebElement elem : divList) {
    System.out.print(elem.getText());
}
```

[The Selenium JavaDocs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html). In particular, you want to see [WebDriver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html), [WebElement](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html).

[And the Selenium documentation in examples.](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations) Read it.

Comment: got this almost working, except i need to user findElements instead of findElement. Im using selenium because i first need to post some forms.

Comment: Yep, that was the other option. That way, you can get multiple elements. I'll edit it into the answer. I'm glad it helped!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It works now! just one thing, in you last example [WebElements] has to be <WebElements>. Thanks again!

Comment: Hah, bad typo :). If you have more questions, feel free to start a SO chat room and post a link to it here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this question:

[Using Java to find substring of a bigger string using Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600733/using-java-to-find-substring-of-a-bigger-string-using-regular-expression)

The only difficulty here is the regex you'll have to build but this is not a java issue.

Do read the comments on line breaks and the use of Pattern.DOTALL flag.

EDIT: as Luciano mentioned, I would look for a better way of reading the html.  Your `String` might contain more that one `<div align="center">` and you might not get only what you wanted in the first place.

EDIT:

This code seems to work:

```
String html = "<div align=\"center\">text</div>";

Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("<div align=\"center\">(.*?)</div>");

Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(html);
while (m.find()) {
    String s = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: i've allready tried it with regex but i couldn't get it to work. ill try luciano suggestion. thanks for your input

Comment: When im adding that there is a problem with downloading the html, so its not working yet

Comment: I guess it's a server problem of the website, ill try it after diner again and will let you know my results with it

Comment: When i use this it doesn't work. Your example does but when i change String html = "<div align=\"center\">text</div>"; to String html = webdata.getPageSource(); It doesn't show anything. The string html isn't empty, when i print him it shows the whole source of the page.

Comment: Have you tried the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag?  `Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("<div align=\"center\">(.*?)</div>",Pattern.DOTALL);`

Comment: Anyway Slanec answer is the way to go !!

Answer (score 0):

With selenium, instead of downloading the source page, use selenium to get hold of the html element from where you would want to fetch the text, either by using xpath or some locator([Selenium Locating strategies](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#locating-elements))..and then do a getText..something like..selenium.getText(locator_of_element).  If its a list of elements, then you can loop through using index in front of the locator eg. //div[0], //div[i] etc

Hope it helps..