# Download URL in Android

Tags: java, android, download

I've tried to download HTML content from the URL `http://google.com` and another URL.

I tried:

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.com/");
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

And although I've tried `InputStream`, it didn't work the same.

```
try {

    URL url = new URL("http://google.com/");

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        System.out.print(urlConnection.getResponseCode());


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print("Error: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
```

At the end I see the `catch` and the `e.getMessage` is `null`. If I debug it, `urlConnection.getResponseCode()` is returning `-1`.

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace()`, rather than `System.out.print("Error: "+e.getMessage());`. You are throwing away lots of useful information (e.g. the type of the exception).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch HTML in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462/how-to-fetch-html-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set DoOutput where you will not do output. You do not set DoInput where you do input. Remove the chunked streaming mode.