# How to get webpage content on Kotlin

Tags: android, sockets, web, kotlin

I am new in Kotlin Programming and I want to get [Google](http://www.google.com) html content
But i don't know how can I do this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `HttpUrlConnection` ([Java example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462/how-to-fetch-html-in-java)) but I recommend using higher level libraries like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). You can then use CSS selectors to get specific elements from the document (so you may not actually need the HTML code in your app).

You can fetch Google's index page this way:

```
val doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get()
val html = doc.outerHtml()
```

If you need the raw HTML which is sent by Google, you can use this code:

```
val conn = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").method(Method.GET)
val resp = conn.execute()
val html = resp.body()
```