# parse meta tags in Java

Tags: java, html, xml, parsing

I have a collection of HTML documents for which I need to parse the contents of the <meta> tags in the <head> section. These are the only HTML tags whose values I'm interested in, i.e. I don't need to parse anything in the <body> section.

I've attempted to parse these values using the XPath support provided by JDom. However, this isn't working out too well because a lot of the HTML in the <body> section is not valid XML.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I might go about parsing these tag values in manner that can deal with malformed HTML?

Cheers,
Don

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quick way to find a value in HTML (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415/quick-way-to-find-a-value-in-html-java) (though the answers here are better)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can likely use the [Jericho HTML Parser](http://jerichohtml.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html). In particular, have a look at [this](http://jerichohtml.sourceforge.net/samples/console/src/FindSpecificTags.java) to see how you can go about finding specific tags.

Answer (score 2):

If it suits your application you can use [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to convert HTML to valid XML, and then use as much XPath as you like!

Answer (score 0):

[JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) should provide a good starting point for this.