# How to extract meta tags from website on android?

Tags: android, html, meta-tags

is there a smart way to read the content of metatags from an URL in android? I'll show a webpage in the webview on android and want to read some informations from the metatag inside. Is the only way to parse the string of the webpage to find the special string "meta name="x-..." content="!!!" or is there any smarter way??

Comment: You shouldn't parse the string.  Instead, use sax parser or some other way of reading structured data and just get the relevant elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse meta tags in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299334/parse-meta-tags-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

A smart way would be using [Jericho Library](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html)

supposing you have an html file like this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" debug="true">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252"/>
<link href="styleUrgente.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 320, initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no"/>
<meta name="joc-height" value="120"/>
<meta name="joc-enabled" value="1"/>
</head>
<body margin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">
<script src="chrome-extension://bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench/googleChrome.js"/>
</html>
```

for example to get the value of meta tag with name "`joc-height`" you can use this method:

```
public String extractAllText(String htmlText){
        Source source = new Source(htmlText);   
        String strData = "";        
        List<Element> elements = source.getAllElements("meta");

        for(Element element : elements )
        {
            final String id = element.getAttributeValue("name"); // Get Attribute 'id'
             if( id != null && id.equals("joc-height")){
                 strData = element.getAttributeValue("value").toString();    
                   }
        }
        return strData;
    }
```

and you will get the value of "`120`"

Comment: how to get from url?

Comment: @Prasad download the content of the url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654876/http-get-using-android-httpurlconnection and then use the method described in the answer.