# How can I make a url reader in android

Tags: android, url

I know how to get data from a url but my point is when a user paste a url in my EditText I want to expand the url to get the description and main image from the url. When we paste a url in a facebook/google + EditText it will read and expand the url so I want just like that. In web development we can get those data from html < meta > tag but in android how can I just get the < meta > data rather than whole url html.

Comment: Have you had a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965708/how-to-extract-meta-tags-from-website-on-android

Comment: Not sure if that's exactly what you want to do but you can pull the meta tags from websites using that library.

Comment: @AndrewQuebe wow I have been searching hundred time in google but u solve my problem just in a moment thank!

Comment: I'll make this an answer so you can mark it.

Comment: Make sure you press the check mark...it marks it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this question on So: [How to extract meta tags from website on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965708/how-to-extract-meta-tags-from-website-on-android)

You can pull the meta tags from websites using that library.

## Edit:

Due to the lack of documentation on that other library, I did some research and found something better. There is something called [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/) which is a .jar file and can be imported into your libs folder in your Android Studio project.

jSoup let's you pull tags from websites using a method known as scraping. Disclaimer: make sure you have permission to scrape a website depending on what you're doing with the results. [Here's](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/parsing-html-in-android-with-jsoup.html) a great tutorial on how to use jSoup to pull tags into Android. It has a really well laid out example.

Hopefully this works a little better.

Comment: But there is one more problem I have no import any library yet.. How could I do that?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Eclipse? Android Studio?

Comment: I'm going to revise the answer...gimme a sec.

Comment: Okay take your time and really grateful